# Numbas parallel vectorized functions

Tags: python, numpy, parallel-processing, numba

I'm currently experimenting with `numba` and especially `vectorized` functions, so I created a `sum` vectorized function (because it is easy to compare this to `np.sum`.

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

@nb.vectorize([nb.float64(nb.float64, nb.float64)])
def numba_sum(element1, element2):
    return element1 + element2

@nb.vectorize([nb.float64(nb.float64, nb.float64)], target='parallel')
def numba_sum_parallel(element1, element2):
    return element1 + element2

array = np.ones(elements)
np.testing.assert_almost_equal(numba_sum.reduce(array), np.sum(array))
np.testing.assert_almost_equal(numba_sum_parallel.reduce(array), np.sum(array))
```

Depending on the number of `elements` the parallel code does not return the same number as the `cpu` targeted code. I think that's because of something related to the usual threading-problems (but why? Is that a Bug in Numba or something that just happens when using parallel execution?). Funny is that sometimes it works, sometimes it does not. Sometimes it fails with `elements=1000` sometimes it starts failing on `elements=100000`.

For example:

```
AssertionError: 
Arrays are not almost equal to 7 decimals
 ACTUAL: 93238.0
 DESIRED: 100000.0
```

and if I run it again

```
AssertionError: 
Arrays are not almost equal to 7 decimals
 ACTUAL: 83883.0
 DESIRED: 100000.0
```

My question is now: Why would I ever want a *parallel* vectorized function? My understanding is that the purpose of a `vectorized` function is to provide the [numpy-ufunc](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/ufuncs.html#methods) possibilities but I tested `reduce` and `accumulate` and they stop working at some (variable) number of elements and who wants an unreliable function?

I'm using `numba 0.23.1`, `numpy 1.10.1` with `python 3.5.1`.

Comment: I suspect you'd have more luck filing it as the bug it clearly is rather than posting it here.

Comment: My question is actually not about the bug, it's about where "parallel" vectorized functions would make sense given that it can lead to such problems.

Comment: Ah - I see. Ideally it'd keep a separate counter in each thread and add them together at the end (look up OpenMP `reduce` as an example of a C/Fortran multithreading interface, which does this). If this is done, the answer should be reproducible (and right!).

Comment: are you sure that your algorithm is numerically stable?

Comment: @denfromufa what do you mean?

Comment: Did you report this bug? Because I use numba 0.35.0 and still can see it...

Comment: Yes i also reported the issue https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/1721

Answer (score 0):

You ask:

> where would "parallel" vectorized functions make sense given that it can lead to such problems

Given that ufuncs produced by `numba.vectorize(target='parallel')` have defective `reduce()` methods, the question is what can we do with them that is useful?

In your case, the ufunc does addition.  A useful application of this with `target='parallel'` is elementwise addition of two arrays:

```
numba_sum(array, array)
```

This is indeed faster than a single-core solution, and seems not to be impacted by the bugs that cripple `reduce()` and friends.