# Usage of parallel option in numba.jit decoratior makes function give wrong result

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, jit, numba

Given two opposite corners of a rectangle `(x1, y1)` and `(x2, y2)` and two radii `r1` and `r2`, find the ratio of points that lie between the circles defined by the radii `r1` and `r2` to the total number of points in the rectangle.

Simple NumPy approach:

```
def func_1(x1,y1,x2,y2,r1,r2,n):
     x11,y11 = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(x1,x2,n),np.linspace(y1,y2,n))
     z1 = np.sqrt(x11**2+y11**2)
     a = np.where((z1>(r1)) & (z1<(r2)))
     fill_factor = len(a[0])/(n*n)
     return fill_factor
```

Next I tried to optimize this function with the `jit` decorator from numba. When I use:

```
nopython = True
```

The function is faster and gives the right output. But when I also add:

```
parallel = True
```

The function is faster but gives the wrong result. 
I know that this has something to do with my `z` matrix since that is not being updated properly.

```
@jit(nopython=True,parallel=True)
def func_2(x1,y1,x2,y2,r1,r2,n):
    x_ = np.linspace(x1,x2,n)
    y_ = np.linspace(y1,y2,n)
    z1 = np.zeros((n,n))
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            z1[i][j] = np.sqrt((x_[i]*x_[i]+y_[j]*y_[j]))
    a = np.where((z1>(r1)) & (z1<(r2)))
    fill_factor = len(a[0])/(n*n)
    return fill_factor
```

Test values :

```
x1 = 1.0
x2 = -1.0
y1 = 1.0
y2 = -1.0
r1 = 0.5
r2 = 0.75
n = 25000
```

Additional info : Python version : 3.6.1, Numba version : 0.34.0+5.g1762237, NumPy version : 1.13.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with `parallel=True` is that it's a black-box. Numba doesn't even guarantee that it will actually parallelize anything. It uses heuristics to find out if it's parallelizable and what *could* be done in parallel. These can fail and in your example they do fail, just like in [my experiments with `parallel` and numba](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35459065/5393381). That makes `parallel` untrustworthy and I would advise *against* using it!

In newer versions (0.34) `prange` was added an you could have more luck with that. It can't be applied in this case because `prange` works like `range` and that's different from `np.linspace`...

Just a note: You can avoid building `z` and doing the `np.where` in your function completely, you could just do the checks explicitly:

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

@nb.njit   # equivalent to "jit(nopython=True)".
def func_2(x1,y1,x2,y2,r1,r2,n):
    x_ = np.linspace(x1,x2,n)
    y_ = np.linspace(y1,y2,n)
    cnts = 0
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            z = np.sqrt(x_[i] * x_[i] + y_[j] * y_[j])
            if r1 < z < r2:
                cnts += 1
    fill_factor = cnts/(n*n)
    return fill_factor
```

That should also provide some speedup compared to your function, maybe even more than using `parallel=True` (if it would work correctly).

Comment: Thank You! 
Another thing I'd like to add is that one does not have to take the square root of z and can directly compare the squares instead(as pointed out my by advisor).
Apart from that I tried to see what could have gone wrong with the code and I think it may have been that a race condition developed and one should not blindly use the parallel option as you had previously pointed out.

Comment: Yes, I also think it's some kind of race-condition but I inspected the generated LLVM code and I don't see how. The race condition would need to happen within `np.where` (because there are no subsequent writes to the same array position in your `z`) but it's kind of ominous how that could lead to a race condition. But I'm curious about the square root: Is it actually faster to compute the square root instead of two multiplications and one addition?