# Increasing performance of highly repeated numpy array index operations

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, memoryview

In my program code I've got `numpy` value arrays and `numpy` index arrays. Both are preallocated and predefined during program initialization.
Each part of the program has one array `values` on which calculations are performed, and three index arrays `idx_from_exch`, `idx_values` and `idx_to_exch`. There is on global value array to exchange the values of several parts: `exch_arr`.
The index arrays have between 2 and 5 indices most of the times, seldomly (most probably never) more indices are needed. `dtype=np.int32`, `shape` and values are constant during the whole program run. Thus I set `ndarray.flags.writeable=False` after initialization, but this is optional. The index values of the index arrays `idx_values` and `idx_to_exch` are sorted in numerical order, `idx_source` *may be sorted*, but there is no way to define that. All index arrays corresponding to one value array/part have the same `shape`.
The `values` arrays and also the `exch_arr` usually have between 50 and 1000 elements. `shape` and `dtype=np.float64` are constant during the whole program run, the values of the arrays change in each iteration.
Here are the example arrays:

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

values = np.random.rand(100) * 100  # just some random numbers
exch_arr = np.random.rand(60) * 3  # just some random numbers
idx_values = np.array((0, 4, 55, -1), dtype=np.int32)  # sorted but varying steps
idx_to_exch = np.array((7, 8, 9, 10), dtype=np.int32)  # sorted and constant steps!
idx_from_exch = np.array((19, 4, 7, 43), dtype=np.int32)  # not sorted and varying steps
```

The example indexing operations look like this:

```
values[idx_values] = exch_arr[idx_from_exch]  # get values from exchange array
values *= 1.1  # some inplace array operations, this is just a dummy for more complex things
exch_arr[idx_to_exch] = values[idx_values]  # pass some values back to exchange array
```

Since these operations are being applied once per iteration for several million iterations, speed is crucial. I've been looking into many different ways of increasing indexing speed [in my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46041811/performance-of-various-numpy-fancy-indexing-methods-also-with-numba), but forgot to be specific enough considering my application (especially getting values by indexing with constant index arrays and passing them to another indexed array).
The best way to do it seems to be fancy indexing so far. I'm currently also experimenting with `numba` `guvectorize`, but it seems that it is not worth the effort since my arrays are quite small.
`memoryviews` would be nice, but since the index arrays do not necessarily have consistent steps, I know of no way to use `memoryviews`.

So is there any faster way to do repeated indexing? Some way of predefining memory address arrays for each indexing operation, as `dtype` and `shape` are always constant? `ndarray.__array_interface__` gave me a memory address, but I wasn't able to use it for indexing. I thought about something like:

```
stride_exch = exch_arr.strides[0]
mem_address = exch_arr.__array_interface__['data'][0]
idx_to_exch = idx_to_exch * stride_exch + mem_address
```

Is that feasible?
I've also been looking into using `strides` directly with `as_strided`, but as far as I know only consistent strides are allowed and my problem would require inconsistent `strides`.

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

---

**edit:**
I just corrected a massive error in my example calculation!
The operation `values = values * 1.1` **changes the memory address** of the array. All my operations in the program code are layed out to **not change the memory address** of the arrays, because alot of other operations rely on using memoryviews. Thus I replaced the dummy operation with the correct in-place operation: `values *= 1.1`

Comment: Is reordering `values` and `exch_arr` possible?  Slices don't copy memory, so if you can structure your data so you're using contiguous blocks, it'll be much faster.

Comment: Unluckily not. There are too many interconnected parts which all have their `value` array and index arrays and the `exch_arr` connects them. For a tree like net topology with lots of connections in between, ordering is impossible. `value` arrays represent physical properties, thus also no reordering possible. All other arrays where at least some kind of a repeated/ordered structure exists, are already transformed to memoryviews, but in the presented question this is unluckily not possible.

Comment: Have you found any way to speed up indexing?

Comment: @MrCheatak No, I had to accept using fancy indexing. But I guess indexing operations using numba were improved in the last three years. The only workaround I currently see is storing single-cell memoryviews, such as `values[4:5]` in a list/tuple and iterating over the list/tuple in a jit-compiled function. I guess this should be substantially faster than repeated fancy indexing. But you have to decide, if it is worth the effort...

Answer (score 0):

One solution to getting round expensive fancy indexing using numpy boolean arrays is using numba and skipping over the False values in your numpy boolean array.

Example implementation:

```
@numba.guvectorize(['float64[:], float64[:,:], float64[:]'], '(n),(m,n)->(m)', nopython=True, target="cpu")
def test_func(arr1, arr2, inds, res):
    for i in range(arr1.shape[0]):
        if not inds[i]:
            continue
        for j in range(arr2.shape[0]):
            res[j, i] = arr1[i] + arr2[j, i]
```

Of course, play around with the numpy data types (smaller byte sizes will run faster) and target being `"cpu"` or `"parallel"`.