# Fast way to apply a mapping array to all elements in a numpy array?

Tags: python, performance, numpy

Right now, I have code that basically looks like:

```
for x in range(img.shape[0]):
    for y in range(image.shape[1]):
        output[x,y] = map[ input[x,y] ]
```

where `output`, `input` and `map` are all numpy arrays (map is size 256, all are type uint8).

This works, but it's slow.  Loops like this should be in C.  That's what numpy is for.

Is there a numpy function (or a cv2 function, I'm already importing that anyway) that will do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about?

```
output = map[input]
```

Comment: No need to flatten and reshape, `map_[input]` just works. (I renamed `map` to `map_` for the usual reasons).

Comment: Yep.  I don't know how sensitive this is to my system, but `map.take(input)` is consistently a little to a fair bit faster than `map[input]`.

Comment: And either of these is *substantially* faster than `f[a.flatten()].reshape(a.shape)`.

Comment: Ah yeah the reshapes are not required. As for speed; the reshapes are O(1) so if they are noticable all that proves your test arrays are tiny

Comment: That's what I would have thought, but these were actually based on an image array with something on the order of `n = int(1e8)` elements.  Each of `f[a]`, `f.take(a)`, and `f[a.flatten()].reshape(a.shape)` take respectively 687ms, 429ms, and 719ms on average.  The differences are starker when you have `a <- a.astype(np.intp)`.    In this case both `f[a]` and `f.take(a)` are hover around 110ms and `f[a.flatten()].reshape(a.shape)` is typically greater than 300ms.

Comment: ah; flatten copies, whereas ravel makes a view where it can. That nuance wasnt on my radar; not the most self-descriptive names either... but with ravel I wouldnt expect a difference

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [`np.take`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.take.html) which is as simple as `map.take(input)`.  Both this and Eelco's solution are much faster than yours; this is about 70 percent faster than Eelco's system though your mileage may vary, and for `input.shape >> (1e4, 1e4)` you'll need a better solution.

One place to start is [Performance of various numpy fancy indexing methods, also with numba] ([Performance of various numpy fancy indexing methods, also with numba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46041811/performance-of-various-numpy-fancy-indexing-methods-also-with-numba)) which details various performance-related facts for this generic problem (*i.e.* how do we use one *k*-dimensional array to index some other *n*-dimensional array in more than just trivial ways).

If you have something like `Anaconda` installed, you could try to use `Numba` to `jit` `np.ndarray.take(...)` and see how much performance you can buy.  The link above explains this as well.